# Convert to std::unique_ptr implicitly

Tags: c++

I am using std::unique_ptr to allocate and destroy CUDA memory automatically

```
template <typename T>
struct CudaDeleter {
    void operator()(T *ptr) { cudaFree(reinterpret_cast<void *>(ptr)); }
};

template <typename T>
using CudaPtr = std::unique_ptr<T, CudaDeleter<T>>;
```

I have some helper functions to convert a `std::vector<T>` directly to a `CudaPtr`

```
namespace cuda {
template <typename T>
auto make_unique(std::size_t size)
{
    T *p = nullptr;
    cudaMalloc((&p), size * sizeof(T));
    CudaPtr<T> ptr(p);
    return ptr;
}

template <typename T>
auto make_unique(const std::vector<T> &v)
{
    auto d = make_unique<T>(v.size());
    cudaMemcpy(d.get(), v.data(), sizeof(T) * v.size(), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);

    return d;
}
}
```

which I use in the following way

```
std::vector<int> m_dist; // assume it has content
auto dists = cuda::make_unique(m_dist);
```

I would like to know if there is any way to implicitly `make_unique` from the std::vector directly to the `CudaPtr`, without explicitly calling `make_unique`.

Comment: `reinterpret_cast<void *>`: That's redundant. The conversion to `void*` is implicit. "_I would like to know if there is any way to implicitly [...]_": You can make `CudaPtr` a class derived from `std::unique_ptr<T, CudaDeleter<T>>` and then give it a converting constructor from `std::vector`. But that such conversions happen implicitly in C++ is usually considered one of its problems. Do you really want to have such a costly operation happen implicitly?

Comment: I think it is not a good idea to do overally. Because from what I understand in your code, `std::vector<>` represent memory in host and your `unique_ptr<>` represent memory in device and that's why you need that `cudaMemCpy()`. So I think it is not a good idea to implicitly convert that `vector` to `unique_ptr`. But if you like to have a vector for your device memory too, you **may** be able to achieve a very consistent way by using allocator. create a cuda memory allocator and create your vector based on that.

Comment: I like the idea of the std::vector with an allocator. However, I am not using the vector API, the CudaPtr is just for uploading data to the GPU to be used in hand crafted kernels. You are right that I probably dont want to do this costly operation implicitly. But I was tired of typing it all the time..

Comment: Tired of typing is a horrendously bad reason for wanting an implicit conversion.

Comment: Agree, Im going to take the advice in the comments and keep writing the explicit call.